# Core Data background thread not updating record

Tags: ios, core-data, grand-central-dispatch

I am having an issue with Core Data in a background GCD thread... I want to update a record, but after fetching it and setting the values it doesn't seem to actually save the updated record.

`isUpdate` is a BOOL I have setup that tells me whether I am running a first time parse/save or whether it's a record I need to update. In my case, when I update a record it doesn't actually seem to update in my store.

I'm using MagicalRecord helpers. Here's my code:

```
// Create background context
NSManagedObjectContext *backgroundContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
[backgroundContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator defaultStoreCoordinator]];
// Save the background context and handle the save notification
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(backgroundContextDidSave:)
                                             name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                           object:backgroundContext];

// Parsing data...
//..

Record *record;
if (!isUpdate) {
    record = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Record" inManagedObjectContext:backgroundContext];
} else {
    NSPredicate *recordPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.tag == %@", [[node attributeForName:@"tag"] stringValue]];
    record = [Record findFirstWithPredicate:recordPredicate];
}
[record setTitle:[[recordNode attributeForName:@"title"] stringValue]];

// Parsing other data...
//..

NSError *error = nil;
// save the context
[backgroundContext save:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
}
```

And here's the notification:

```
- (void)backgroundContextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // Make sure we're on the main thread when updating the main context
    if (![NSThread isMainThread]) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(backgroundContextDidSave:)
                           withObject:notification
                        waitUntilDone:NO];
        return;
    }
    // merge in the changes to the main context on the main thread
    [[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext] mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
}
```

Comment: did you set breakpoints, first in the if/else  check on isUpdate, to see which one gets called; and then in the notification handler? Did you check that mergeChangesFromContext... is being called, or it's not?

Comment: Yes, both are being called correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing two contexts. This code is probably bad:

```
 record = [Record findFirstWithPredicate:recordPredicate];
```

I assume that this finds record in different context instead of Your backgroundContext. You should change it to something like this:

```
 record = [Record findFirstWithPredicate:recordPredicate inManagedObjectContext:backgroundContext];
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that before, but I get this error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can only use -performBlockAndWait: on an NSManagedObjectContext that was created with a queue.'` I am creating the background context inside the queue. Any ideas?

Comment: By the way, this error comes from MagicalRecord `+ (NSArray *) MR_executeFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)request inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context`

Comment: Another update: I had to use the MR helper method `[NSManagedObjectContext contextForCurrentThread]` but I still don't see any changes to my data if I update the XML and parse it.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer. It essentially did come down to threading issues, which I solved by using MagicalRecord's lovely `saveDataInBackgroundWithBlock` which handles all the headaches that is Core Data and threading. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Changes made in other context must be merged to main context - otherwise contexts will not see changes in other contexts. Of course You can kill your app and you will see all changes. As You see, MagicalRecords makes this easly for You in `saveDataInBackgroundWithBlock`. Check their source codes to see how they made it. It's very good to understand how merging contexts works.

Comment: No the changes weren't being merged properly even though the notification for saving the main context was firing so there were changes initially because the context was still in memory, but as soon as I would relaunch, the sqlite file was empty - it was always empty, even at first launch right after parsing, even though the context would return data (from cache). I'm not 100% what the issues was, but MagicalRecord basically takes care of the threading and context merging for you with the above method, so that helped me out a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Your code sounds quite strange to me.

Why do you register `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` notification in the background thread? Maybe I'm wrong but you need to register that notification in a different point in your app.

If you want to make it works you could register that notification in the main thread. For example you could do it in the `AppDelegate`.

For example in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method you cand do

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(backgroundContextDidSave:)
                                             name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                           object:backgroundContext];
```

Then, always within the `AppDelegate`, you can merge the changes with the method you wrote:

```
- (void)backgroundContextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // Make sure we're on the main thread when updating the main context
    if (![NSThread isMainThread]) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(backgroundContextDidSave:)
                           withObject:notification
                        waitUntilDone:YES];
        return;
    }
    // merge in the changes to the main context on the main thread
    [[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext] mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
}
```

The code performs these steps:

1. First checks if you are running in the main thread or not.
2. Since the notification you register could originate from a thread
   different from the main one, you need to perform the selector on the
   main thread.
3. Finally performs the merge with the notification that contains the
   changes you made in background.

Once done, you can see that the main context is updated with the changes made in the other one.

**Edit**

Maybe you can try also to change the `waitUntilDone` to YES.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with that part of the code in terms of what your answer suggests to be honest. The initial parsing where I insert new objects work perfectly fine, it's the fetching of the records and then updating each record that doesn't work.